# Accessing data in a strangely formatted JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, formatting, nested

I was given the following JSON format and I am having a difficult time getting to the information. I want to put it into a data table.

```
"data":    {
       "HeadingOne":{

      "Columns":["Row1", "Row2"], 
      "Data":[["firstData", "secondData"]]

   }

}
```

I am told that I should be able to access this data but I have absolutely no clue how to get to "firstData" in datatables. (from datatables.net) This is what I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "<%= request.getContextPath()%>/ajax/mastermenu.txt",
        "columns":[
            {"data": "HeadingOne.Data.Row1"}        
            ] 
    } );
} );
```

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row1</th>
                <th>Row2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: This json is not valid

Comment: This is invalid JSON, the object isn't closed properly.

Comment: It's missing a `}`, is this part of a JSON?

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, you're missing a `}` at the end. After you fix that this should work.

Assuming the object is called `data`, this will get you `"firstData"`

```
console.log(data.HeadingOne.Data[0][0]); // "firstData"
```

Comment: This works, but I cannot figure out how to work with it in Datatables. I dont suppose this is something you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yeuch. But:

```
var data = {
    "HeadingOne":{
        "Columns":["Row1", "Row2"], 
        "Data":[
               ["firstData", "secondData"]
               ]
    }
}
var firstData = data['HeadingOne']['Data'][0][0]
```

*Note*: I had to add a final `}` to that block otherwise it was not valid

If you're trying to access firstData by name, hopefully it's obvious that it won't work as it's contained in an array within an array (hence the `[0][0]`).